# Why isnt sql management studio integrated in visual studio?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I have both SQL Server 2005 and Visual Studio 2008 installed and think it would be really nice to have SQL Management Studio integrated directly within Visual Studio. Is there a way to make that happen? What about in VS 2010 with SQL Server 2008?

I find the Visual Studio Server Explorer window to be much slower too than the Object Browser in SQL Server's Management Studio... it would be nice to never really need to use the Server Explorer.

Comment: "Slower than the Object Browser" I'm not sure. I find both the thing in VS 2008 and SSMS to be horribly slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that they are separate products sold separately (different target audiences).

With that being said, it would be nice if there was some kind of SQL Server Management Studio plugin for Visual Studio instead of having to have 2 different apps open.

Answer (score 2):

Why would a SQL Server DBA want to install Visual Studio ??

BTW: the SQL Server Management Studio shell really *is* Visual Studio behind the covers....

Answer (score 2):

The only long way I can think of is by creating a custom Visual Studio plugin that starts SQL Management window finds it HWND subclasses it and changes it's parent to a control on your Visual Studio Plugin dialog.

If you build it i'd use it :)

Comment: Yes, me too, I'd use it as well ! :-)